# How to list the profiles only when address exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the relation set up this way, `Profile has_many Addresses`. In the index action, I am doing `@profiles = Profile.all`, which is giving me all the profiles, but I want to query Profile in such a way that, it will list only profiles when atleast one address exists for a profile.

The current approach I have is, I am checking in the view if the profile has an address, but I feel this is not right. Is there anyway to query like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this. It will fetch only those profiles which have an address linked to them.

```
@profiles = Profile.joins(:addresses).distinct
```

Comment: What is the difference if I use includes in the above query?

Comment: Hmm, just try it! But `includes` is use purely for eager loading, it is a separate sql statement that doesn't do any joining. So not much use in filtering out profiles, not on it's own at least.